# boost exceptions in a shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, exception

EDIT: RESOLVED. The problem was much more benign - I had two functions that were called inside one another in one line of code - both used `lexical_cast` and the *other* one was crashing. It's interesting that I was only able to find this out by sprinkling in a lot of `cout`'s as there was no backtrace upon crash and when debugging line be line, gdb was for whatever reason showing the wrong `lexical_cast` as the culprit (and I didn't see the other one, sigh). Thanks for the help!

---

I'm using gcc 4.1.2 and boost 1.48. I have the following code in a shared library inside a template function:

```
try {
  boost::lexical_cast<T>(s);
}
catch (...) {
  std::cout << "Caught it" << std::endl;
  throw;
}
```

The cast fails, but the exception doesn't get caught (it *does* propagate and terminate the program, but this catch-clause doesn't catch it). `T` is `long` and `s` is a `std::string` equal to `"234a234"`. (I also tried wrapping the boost includes in `#pragma GCC visibility push(default)` and also tried adding `-shared-libgcc` flag when linking, and that didn't do anything.)

It gets better though. In the following two cases the exception DOES get caught:

```
try {
  throw boost::bad_lexical_cast();
}
catch (...) {
  std::cout << "Caught it" << std::endl;
  throw;
}
```

and amazingly this one:

```
try {
  boost::lexical_cast<T>(s);
  throw boost::bad_lexical_cast();
}
catch (...) {
  std::cout << "Caught it" << std::endl;
  throw;
}
```

Any ideas on what's going on and more importantly how to fix this?

Comment: Why not catch boost::bad_lexical_cast& or std::exception& instead?  It doesn't answer your question but maybe it'll help the compiler out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce on my machine but I'm using a different compiler

```
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
```

I used the following as a test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T printLexicalCast(const std::string& s){
    T t;
    try {
         t = boost::lexical_cast<T>(s);
         cout << "cast is [" << t << "] from string [" << s << "]" << endl;
    }
    catch (const boost::bad_lexical_cast& e ) {
      std::cout << "Caught bad lexical cast with error " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch( ... ){
        std::cout << "Unknown exception caught!" << endl;
    }
    return t;
}   


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::string badString("234a234");
    long l1 = printLexicalCast<long>(badString); //exception


    std::string goodString("123456");
    long l2 = printLexicalCast<long>(goodString); 

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Caught bad lexical cast with error bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
cast is [123456] from string [123456]
```

If I remove the bad_lexical_cast catch the catch-all works.

```
Unknown exception caught!
cast is [123456] from string [123456]
```

Maybe this is just a compiler bug?  I found this on the boost-users list

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/conversion-lexical-cast-doesn-t-throw-td2593967.html

Comment: As far as I understand this is a shared library only issue.

I can catch the exceptions when I don't use any libraries, but once I put the code in a library it stops working. There is some discussion about exceptions in shared libraries [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) and [here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2008/09/40268.php), but those things didn't help me.

Comment: For completeness - my actual code structure is slightly more complicated - the exception is inside a library that's used by another library that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

That will happen if `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` is getting defined somewhere.

Comment: It's not. Maybe I was a little unclear - the boost::bad_lexical_cast exception IS thrown and the program terminates, but that exception does NOT get caught in the catch block.

Comment: That is bizarre.  I see your catch clause rethrows it.  Have you set a breakpoint there, or are you counting on `std::cout` to see if you caught the exception?

Comment: I tried setting a breakpoint - it never gets there. In fact when it dies I can't even get a normal backtrace - it just shows `libgcc` smth and then just a couple of frames of `???`'s